# Java web.xml location for embedded jetty

Tags: java, jetty, web.xml, project-structure

I'm trying to understand the way we should configure the web application.
Now i have a simple gradle project with embedded jetty

[image: layout structure]

Dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    compile('org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-servlet:9.3.10.v20160621')
    compile('org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-webapp:9.3.10.v20160621')

    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

Application main:

```
package test;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        System.out.println(">> Running");
        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setDescriptor("src/main/resources/WEB-INF/web.xml");
        webAppContext.setResourceBase("/");
        webAppContext.setContextPath("/");

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(webAppContext);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

In web.xml I defined only ServletContextListener implementation to find if it was catched with application.

My problem is: `webAppContext.setDescriptor("src/main/resources/WEB-INF/web.xml")`
Jetty can find web.xml only with this weird location path.

Why do I need to target it from project folder?
If I run jar task with gradle the wouldn't be any src directory inside the jar.

Is exist a way to something like: `App.class.getResource("/WEB-INF/web.xml")` and load web.xml related to classpath?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems it was some class loaders issue.

After some further searches I ended with next solution:

```
public class App {
    private static final String WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION = "webapp";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println(">> Running");

        WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
        webAppContext.setContextPath("/");

        URL webAppDir = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource(WEBAPP_RESOURCES_LOCATION);
        webAppContext.setResourceBase(webAppDir.toURI().toString());

        // if setDescriptor set null or don't used jetty looking for /WEB-INF/web.xml under resource base 
//        webAppContext.setDescriptor(webAppDir.toURI().toString() + "web.xml");

        Server server = new Server(8080);
        server.setHandler(webAppContext);
        server.start();
        server.join();
    }
}
```

An the layout:

[image]

Thanks github user arey for the examle [examle](https://github.com/arey/embedded-jetty-webapp)

Answer (score 2):

your web.xml should be in

```
src/main/webapp/WEB-INF
```

UPD: sorry, pressed submit before finalising the post.

above works for me and then I can run the test like:

```
Server server; //jetty server

private static Integer portNum = 9999;
private static String ENDPOINT_URL = "http://localhost:" + portNum + "/appName/";

@Before 
public void startJetty() throws Exception{
    server = new Server(portNum);
    server.setStopAtShutdown(true);
    WebAppContext webAppContext = new WebAppContext();
    webAppContext.setContextPath("/appName");
    webAppContext.setResourceBase("src/main/webapp");       
    webAppContext.setClassLoader(getClass().getClassLoader());
    server.setHandler(webAppContext);
    server.start();
}

@After
public void stopJetty(){
    try {
        server.stop();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Test
public void serverNotNull(){
    assertNotNull("jetty must be initialised", server);
}
```